# Why can the dot ('.') placeholder be skipped when placed in the column position, but not row position of facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

The documentation for `facet_grid` says:

> the dot in the formula is used to indicate there should be no faceting on this dimension

Which does seem to work as expected for any `(. ~ VAR)` or `(VAR ~ .)` I've tried. However, omitting the dots seems to result in some inconsistent behaviour:

```
library(ggplot2)

# 1. This facets the data across columns
ggplot(data = mpg) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y=hwy)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

# 2. This facets the data across columns
ggplot(data = mpg) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y=hwy)) +
    facet_grid(~ cyl)

# 3. This facets the data across rows
ggplot(data = mpg) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y=hwy)) +
    facet_grid(cyl ~ .)

# 4. This results in an error
ggplot(data = mpg) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y=hwy)) +
    facet_grid(cyl ~)
```

Plot #2 is missing a dot and renders perfectly fine, while Plot #4 is missing a dot and results in:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y=hwy)) +
    facet_grid(cyl ~)"
```

I know this is not really a practical problem as following the proper syntax will not cause any issues, but I am curious to learn more about why removing the dot from the column and row positions results in such different behaviour. Is it a bug that Plot #2 works, or that Plot #4 doesn't work? Or is there some reason why the different outcomes is expected behaviour?

Comment: A formula must have a right hand side but a left hand side is optional, so `~ var` is valid syntax whereas `var ~` is not.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento that makes sense, I see that #4 is the only one without a RHS. Thanks!